# Multiple debian packages without dependencies pollution

Tags: cmake

I am trying to create multiple debian packages using CPack. I have been following the documentation from:

- https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cpack/Component-Install-With-CPack

and

- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CPackComponent.html

However it seems that any `install(COMPONENT)` is being considered for the final packages, including those defined under a `add_subdirectory(EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)`.

Consider the following simple cmake structure:

```
% cat CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)
project(p)
add_subdirectory(dep EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)

# define our install + component
install(FILES main.py
  DESTINATION main
  COMPONENT main-comp
  )

# multiple deb package is desired:
set(CPACK_DEB_COMPONENT_INSTALL ON)

# disable not needed:
set(CPACK_BINARY_STGZ OFF)
set(CPACK_BINARY_TZ OFF)
set(CPACK_SOURCE_TGZ OFF)
#
set(CPACK_BINARY_DEB ON)
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_CONTACT foo@bar.com)
include(CPack)
```

and

```
% cat dep/CMakeLists.txt
install(FILES dep.txt
  DESTINATION dep
  COMPONENT remove-me
  )
```

With:

```
% touch main.py dep/dep.txt
```

On my debian machine (buster) here is what I see:

```
% make package
[...]
CPack: - package: /tmp/p/bin/p-0.1.1-Linux-main-comp.deb generated.
CPack: - package: /tmp/p/bin/p-0.1.1-Linux-remove-me.deb generated.
```

I have no interest in the package related to COMPONENT `remove-me`, is there a way to discard it completely for the list of debian packages to be generated.

For reference:

```
% cmake --version
cmake version 3.18.4
```

---

Use case is where `dep` is actually a `git remote` repository which I am not able to modify (consider it read-only).

Comment: As far as I understand from documentation for [install](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html) command, `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` option just excludes the target from the **full** installation. But **component-specific** installation still includes that target. However, in case of component installations you could select which exact components you want to install by adjusting variable [CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CPackComponent.html#variable:CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL). E.g. being set to `main-comp` only `main-comp.deb` package will be created

Comment: please post as answer, I'll approve asap. thanks much